# Why I can't get medium level for math questions to appear?

Tags: java, swing, if-statement, math, actionlistener

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class MATHfighter extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
   Border border = new LineBorder(Color.WHITE, 3, true);
   Border unborder = new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1, true);
   Container c = getContentPane();
   JPanel gameText = new JPanel();
   JPanel gameMenu = new JPanel();
   JTextField answer = new JTextField(12);
   JTextField result = new JTextField(12);
   JButton bAnswer = new JButton("Answer");
   JButton bNext = new JButton("Next");
   JButton bExit = new JButton("Exit");
   int score = 0;
   JLabel mathQuestion = new JLabel();
   JLabel startText = new JLabel(">");
   JLabel startText1 = new JLabel(">");
   Font headlineFont = new Font("Comic Sans MS",Font.BOLD, 15);
   int typeQ;        
   int number1;
   int number2;
   int number3;
   int life_point = 200;
   int player_lp = 200;
   int r = 0;
   int g = 204;
   int b = 0;
   int r1 = 0;
   int g1 = 204;
   int b1 = 0;
   
   public MATHfighter()
   {
      setLayout(null);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      c.setBackground(Color.BLACK); 
      textGame();
      menuGame();
      bAnswer.addActionListener(this);
      bNext.addActionListener(this);
      bExit.addActionListener(this);
   }
   
   public void textGame()
   {
      gameText.setLayout(null);
      gameText.setBorder(border);
      gameText.setBounds(10,410,290,140);
      gameText.setVisible(true);
      gameText.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
      gameText.add(startText);
      gameText.add(startText1);
      startText.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
      startText1.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
      startText.setFont(headlineFont);
      startText1.setFont(headlineFont);
      add(gameText);
      randomMath();
   }
   
   public void menuGame()
   {
      gameMenu.setLayout(null);
      gameMenu.setBorder(border);
      gameMenu.setBounds(305,410,290,140);
      gameMenu.setVisible(true);
      gameMenu.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
      add(gameMenu);
      gameMenu.add(bAnswer);
      bAnswer.setBorder(border);
      bAnswer.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
      bAnswer.setFont(headlineFont);
      bAnswer.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
      bAnswer.setBounds(10,10,130,50);
      gameMenu.add(bNext);
      bNext.setBorder(border);
      bNext.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
      bNext.setFont(headlineFont);
      bNext.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
      bNext.setBounds(150,10,130,50);
      bNext.setEnabled(false);
      gameMenu.add(bExit);
      bExit.setBorder(border);
      bExit.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
      bExit.setFont(headlineFont);
      bExit.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
      bExit.setBounds(150,70,130,50);
   }
   
   public void randomMath()
   {
      typeQ = (int) (Math.random() * 4) + 1;
      number1 = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 10;
      number2 = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 10;
      number3 = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 10;
      mathQuestion.setFont(headlineFont);
      mathQuestion.setBounds(10,10,290,15);
      mathQuestion.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
      gameText.add(mathQuestion);
      answer.setFont(headlineFont);
      answer.setBorder(unborder);
      answer.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
      answer.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
      startText.setBounds(10,35,20,20);
      answer.setBounds(25,35,250,20);
      gameText.add(answer);
      result.setFont(headlineFont);
      result.setBorder(unborder);
      result.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
      result.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
      result.setBounds(25,65,250,20);
      result.setEditable(false);     
      startText1.setBounds(10,65,20,20);
      gameText.add(result);
      
      if((life_point<=200)&&(life_point>100))
      { 
         if(typeQ==1)
         {
            mathQuestion.setText("> What is " + number1 + " + " + number2 + " ?");
         }
         else if(typeQ==2)
         {
            mathQuestion.setText("> What is " + number1 + " - " + number2 + " ?");
         }
         else if(typeQ==3)
         {
            mathQuestion.setText("> What is " + number1 + " * " + number2 + " ?");
         }
         else if(typeQ==4)
         {
            mathQuestion.setText("> What is " + number1*number2 + " / " + number2 + " ?");
         }
      }
      else if(life_point<=100)
      {
         if(typeQ==1)
         {
            mathQuestion.setText("> What is " + number1 + " * " + number2 + " + " + number3 + " ?");
         }
         else if(typeQ==2)
         {
            mathQuestion.setText("> What is " + number1 + " * " + number2 + " - " + number3 + " ?"); 
         }
         else if(typeQ==3)
         {
            mathQuestion.setText("> What is " + number1*number2 + " / " + number2 + " + " + number3 + " ?");
         }
         else if(typeQ==4)
         {
            mathQuestion.setText("> What is " + number1*number2 + " / " + number2 + " - " + number3 + " ?");
         }
      }
        
   }
   
   public void paint(Graphics gr)
   {
      Color c1 = new Color(r, g, b);
      Color c2 = new Color(r1, g1, b1);
      super.paint(gr);
      gr.setColor(c1);
      gr.fillRect(212, 40, life_point, 30);
      gr.setColor(c2);
      gr.fillRect(212, 400, player_lp, 30);
   }
   
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
   {
      if(e.getSource()==bAnswer)
      {
         try
         {
            int kotae = Integer.parseInt(answer.getText());
            
            if((life_point<=200)&&(life_point>100))
            {
               if(typeQ==1)
               {
                  if ((number1 + number2) != kotae) 
                  {
                     result.setText("" + String.format("%s","Incorrect"));
                     bNext.setEnabled(false);
                     player_lp = player_lp - 20;
                     if(player_lp == 100)
                     {
                        r1=204;
                     }
                     else if(player_lp == 40)
                     {
                        g1=0;
                     }
                     repaint();
                  }
                  else if ((number1 + number2) == kotae) 
                  {
                     result.setText("" + String.format("%s","Correct"));
                     answer.setEditable(false);
                     bNext.setEnabled(true);
                     bAnswer.setEnabled(false);
                     life_point = life_point - 20;
                     if(life_point == 100)
                     {
                        r=204;
                     }
                     else if(life_point == 40)
                     {
                        g=0;
                     }
                     repaint(); 
                  }
               }
                  
               else if(typeQ==2)
               {
                  if ((number1 - number2) != kotae) 
                  {
                     result.setText("" + String.format("%s","Incorrect"));
                     bNext.setEnabled(false);
                     player_lp = player_lp - 20;
                     if(player_lp == 100)
                     {
                        r1=204;
                     }
                     else if(player_lp == 40)
                     {
                        g1=0;
                     }
                     repaint();
                  }
                     
                  else if ((number1 - number2) == kotae) 
                  {
                     result.setText("" + String.format("%s","Correct"));
                     answer.setEditable(false);
                     bNext.setEnabled(true);
                     bAnswer.setEnabled(false);
                     life_point = life_point - 20;
                     if(life_point == 100)
                     {
                        r=204;
                     }
                     else if(life_point == 40)
                     {
                        g=0;
                     }
                     repaint();
                  }  
               }
                  
               else if(typeQ==3)
               {
                  if ((number1 * number2) != kotae) 
                  {
                     result.setText("" + String.format("%s","Incorrect"));
                     bNext.setEnabled(false);
                     player_lp = player_lp - 20;
                     if(player_lp == 100)
                     {
                        r1=204;
                     }
                     else if(player_lp == 40)
                     {
                        g1=0;
                     }
                     repaint();
                  }
                     
                  else if ((number1 * number2) == kotae) 
                  {
                     result.setText("" + String.format("%s","Correct"));
                     answer.setEditable(false); 
                     bNext.setEnabled(true);
                     bAnswer.setEnabled(false); 
                     life_point = life_point - 20;
                     if(life_point == 100)
                     {
                        r=204;
                     }
                     else if(life_point == 40)
                     {
                        g=0;
                     }
                     repaint(); 
                  }
                  
               }
                  
               else if(typeQ==4)
               {
                  if ((number1*number2 / number2) != kotae) 
                  {
                     result.setText("" + String.format("%s","Incorrect"));
                     bNext.setEnabled(false);
                     player_lp = player_lp - 20;
                     if(player_lp == 100)
                     {
                        r1=204;
                     }
                     else if(player_lp == 40)
                     {
                        g1=0;
                     }
                     repaint();
                  }
                  else if ((number1*number2 / number2) == kotae) 
                  {
                     result.setText("" + String.format("%s","Correct"));
                     answer.setEditable(false);
                     bNext.setEnabled(true);
                     bAnswer.setEnabled(false);  
                     life_point = life_point - 20;
                     if(life_point == 100)
                     {
                        r=204;
                     }
                     else if(life_point == 40)
                     {
                        g=0;
                     }
                     repaint();
                  }
               }
            }
            
            if(life_point<=100)
            {
               if(typeQ==1)
               {
                  if ((number1 * number2 + number3) != kotae) 
                  {
                     result.setText("" + String.format("%s","Incorrect"));
                     //bNext.setEnabled(false);
                     player_lp = player_lp - 20;
                     if(player_lp == 100)
                     {
                        r1=204;
                     }
                     else if(player_lp == 40)
                     {
                        g1=0;
                     }
                     repaint();
                  }
                     
                  else if ((number1 * number2 + number3) == kotae) 
                  {
                     result.setText("" + String.format("%s","Correct"));
                     answer.setEditable(false);
                     bNext.setEnabled(true);
                     bAnswer.setEnabled(false);
                     life_point = life_point - 20;
                     if(life_point == 100)
                     {
                        r=204;
                     }
                     else if(life_point == 40)
                     {
                        g=0;
                     }
                     repaint(); 
                  }
               }
               
               else if(typeQ==2)
               {
                  if ((number1 * number2 - number3) != kotae) 
                  {
                     result.setText("" + String.format("%s","Incorrect"));
                     //bNext.setEnabled(false);
                     player_lp = player_lp - 20;
                     if(player_lp == 100)
                     {
                        r1=204;
                     }
                     else if(player_lp == 40)
                     {
                        g1=0;
                     }
                     repaint();
                  }
                     
                  else if ((number1 * number2 - number3) == kotae) 
                  {
                     result.setText("" + String.format("%s","Correct"));
                     answer.setEditable(false);
                     bNext.setEnabled(true);
                     bAnswer.setEnabled(false);
                     life_point = life_point - 20;
                     if(life_point == 100)
                     {
                        r=204;
                     }
                     else if(life_point == 40)
                     {
                        g=0;
                     }
                     repaint(); 
                  }
               }
               
               else if(typeQ==3)
               {
                  if ((number1*number2 / number2 + number3) != kotae) 
                  {
                     result.setText("" + String.format("%s","Incorrect"));
                     //bNext.setEnabled(false);
                     player_lp = player_lp - 20;
                     if(player_lp == 100)
                     {
                        r1=204;
                     }
                     else if(player_lp == 40)
                     {
                        g1=0;
                     }
                     repaint();
                  }
                     
                  else if ((number1*number2 / number2 + number3) == kotae) 
                  {
                     result.setText("" + String.format("%s","Correct"));
                     answer.setEditable(false);
                     bNext.setEnabled(true);
                     bAnswer.setEnabled(false);
                     life_point = life_point - 20;
                     if(life_point == 100)
                     {
                        r=204;
                     }
                     else if(life_point == 40)
                     {
                        g=0;
                     }
                     repaint(); 
                  }
               }
               
               else if(typeQ==4)
               {
                  if ((number1*number2 / number2 - number3) != kotae) 
                  {
                     result.setText("" + String.format("%s","Incorrect"));
                     //bNext.setEnabled(false);
                     player_lp = player_lp - 20;
                     if(player_lp == 100)
                     {
                        r1=204;
                     }
                     else if(player_lp == 40)
                     {
                        g1=0;
                     }
                     repaint();
                  }               
                  else if ((number1*number2 / number2 - number3) == kotae) 
                  {
                     result.setText("" + String.format("%s","Correct"));
                     answer.setEditable(false);
                     bNext.setEnabled(true);
                     bAnswer.setEnabled(false);
                     life_point = life_point - 20;
                     if(life_point == 100)
                     {
                        r=204;
                     }
                     else if(life_point == 40)
                     {
                        g=0;
                     }
                     repaint(); 
                  }
               }
            }
         }
         catch(Exception ex)
         {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"<html><font face='Comic Sans MS' size='3'>INTEGER ONLY, KIDDO");
         }       
      }
      
      else if(e.getSource()==bNext)
      {
          typeQ = (int) (Math.random() * 4) + 1;
          number1 = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 10;
          number2 = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 10;
          result.setText("");
          answer.setText("");
          answer.setEditable(true);
          bNext.setEnabled(false);
          bAnswer.setEnabled(true);
          if(typeQ==1)
          {
            mathQuestion.setText("> What is " + number1 + " + " + number2 + " ?");
          }
          else if(typeQ==2)
          {
            mathQuestion.setText("> What is " + number1 + " - " + number2 + " ?");
          }
          else if(typeQ==3)
          {
            mathQuestion.setText("> What is " + number1 + " * " + number2 + " ?");
          }
          else if(typeQ==4)
          {
            mathQuestion.setText("> What is " + number1*number2 + " / " + number2 + " ?");
          }
      }
      
      else
      {
         System.exit(0);
      }
   }
      
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      MATHfighter fight = new MATHfighter();
      fight.setSize(625,600);
      fight.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

This is the continuation from my last question and I did change while loop to if-else, thank you to others who helped me.

My new problems are that I want a bunch of middle level questions to appear when enemy life point become 100 and below but the problem is my GUI became like this after I answered the fifth question:

[image]

there is a chance that my mathQuestion.setText are not working after I used these code:

```
else if(life_point<=100)
      {
         if(typeQ==1)
         {
            mathQuestion.setText("> What is " + number1 + " * " + number2 + " + " + number3 + " ?");
         }
         else if(typeQ==2)
         {
            mathQuestion.setText("> What is " + number1 + " * " + number2 + " - " + number3 + " ?"); 
         }
         else if(typeQ==3)
         {
            mathQuestion.setText("> What is " + number1*number2 + " / " + number2 + " + " + number3 + " ?");
         }
         else if(typeQ==4)
         {
            mathQuestion.setText("> What is " + number1*number2 + " / " + number2 + " - " + number3 + " ?");
         }
      }
```

and

```
 if(life_point<=100)
            {
               if(typeQ==1)
               {
                  if ((number1 * number2 + number3) != kotae) 
                  {
                     result.setText("" + String.format("%s","Incorrect"));
                     //bNext.setEnabled(false);
                     player_lp = player_lp - 20;
                     if(player_lp == 100)
                     {
                        r1=204;
                     }
                     else if(player_lp == 40)
                     {
                        g1=0;
                     }
                     repaint();
                  }

                  else if ((number1 * number2 + number3) == kotae) 
                  {
                     result.setText("" + String.format("%s","Correct"));
                     answer.setEditable(false);
                     bNext.setEnabled(true);
                     bAnswer.setEnabled(false);
                     life_point = life_point - 20;
                     if(life_point == 100)
                     {
                        r=204;
                     }
                     else if(life_point == 40)
                     {
                        g=0;
                     }
                     repaint(); 
                  }
               }

               else if(typeQ==2)
               {
                  if ((number1 * number2 - number3) != kotae) 
                  {
                     result.setText("" + String.format("%s","Incorrect"));
                     //bNext.setEnabled(false);
                     player_lp = player_lp - 20;
                     if(player_lp == 100)
                     {
                        r1=204;
                     }
                     else if(player_lp == 40)
                     {
                        g1=0;
                     }
                     repaint();
                  }

                  else if ((number1 * number2 - number3) == kotae) 
                  {
                     result.setText("" + String.format("%s","Correct"));
                     answer.setEditable(false);
                     bNext.setEnabled(true);
                     bAnswer.setEnabled(false);
                     life_point = life_point - 20;
                     if(life_point == 100)
                     {
                        r=204;
                     }
                     else if(life_point == 40)
                     {
                        g=0;
                     }
                     repaint(); 
                  }
               }

               else if(typeQ==3)
               {
                  if ((number1*number2 / number2 + number3) != kotae) 
                  {
                     result.setText("" + String.format("%s","Incorrect"));
                     //bNext.setEnabled(false);
                     player_lp = player_lp - 20;
                     if(player_lp == 100)
                     {
                        r1=204;
                     }
                     else if(player_lp == 40)
                     {
                        g1=0;
                     }
                     repaint();
                  }

                  else if ((number1*number2 / number2 + number3) == kotae) 
                  {
                     result.setText("" + String.format("%s","Correct"));
                     answer.setEditable(false);
                     bNext.setEnabled(true);
                     bAnswer.setEnabled(false);
                     life_point = life_point - 20;
                     if(life_point == 100)
                     {
                        r=204;
                     }
                     else if(life_point == 40)
                     {
                        g=0;
                     }
                     repaint(); 
                  }
               }

               else if(typeQ==4)
               {
                  if ((number1*number2 / number2 - number3) != kotae) 
                  {
                     result.setText("" + String.format("%s","Incorrect"));
                     //bNext.setEnabled(false);
                     player_lp = player_lp - 20;
                     if(player_lp == 100)
                     {
                        r1=204;
                     }
                     else if(player_lp == 40)
                     {
                        g1=0;
                     }
                     repaint();
                  }               
                  else if ((number1*number2 / number2 - number3) == kotae) 
                  {
                     result.setText("" + String.format("%s","Correct"));
                     answer.setEditable(false);
                     bNext.setEnabled(true);
                     bAnswer.setEnabled(false);
                     life_point = life_point - 20;
                     if(life_point == 100)
                     {
                        r=204;
                     }
                     else if(life_point == 40)
                     {
                        g=0;
                     }
                     repaint(); 
                  }
               }
```

I really hope that someone can help me about these problem

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

## Introduction

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) and the [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) sections.

The code provided in the question is typical of beginner Java programmers.  All of the code is contained in one class.  Almost all of the variables are class variables.  Some of the variables are poorly named.  Code is copied over and over with minor changes.

Swing layout managers are not used.  Null layouts and absolute positioning are used instead.  The makes for a brittle GUI that's hard to maintain and understand.  I wonder how much effort it took to calculate all of the Swing component offsets?

So, let's see what we can do to improve this code.  Here's the GUI I came up with.

[image: Math Fighter]

## Explanation

Breaking up the code into an application model, a view, and multiple `ActionListeners` helps me to separate my concerns and focus on one part of the application at a time.

### Model

The first thing I did was create an application model class, the `MathFighterModel` class

The `MathFighterModel` class is a plain Java getter/setter class.  It turned out that the class only needed three class variables; the answer to the current math problem, the number of enemy life points, and the number of player life points.

The creation of a math equation is contained in the `generateRandomMathQuestion` method.  I calculate the correct answer and build the question `String` in the same method.  This way, it's much easier to visually verify that the actual calculation matches the question `String`.

By the way, the code is doing integer division when it divides.

The rest of the class is getters and setters.  The original code didn't include a check for either the enemy or player getting to zero life points.  I didn't include the check either.

### View

All Swing applications must start with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that the Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

I used a `JFrame`.  I did not extend a `JFrame`.  The only reason you extend a Swing component, or any Java class, is to override one or more of the class methods.  The `JFrame` has a default `BorderLayout`, which I used to place two `JPanels`.

I created four `JPanels`; a drawing `JPanel` for the health bars, a control `JPanel`, an entry `JPanel`, and a button `JPanel`.  This allows me to separate my concerns and focus on one small part of the GUI at a time.

I create the drawing `JPanel` in a separate class.  I extend `JPanel` because I override the `paintComponent` method.  I call the `super.paintComponent` in the first line of the method to maintain the Swing paint chain.

I calculate the bar colors in the drawing JPanel.  I also centered the bar drawings in the drawing JPanel. Finally, I added the life points number to the center of the bars.

The control `JPanel` is a container that holds the entry `JPanel` and the button `JPanel`.  I used a `FlowLayout` to put the two `JPanels` side by side.

The entry `JPanel` contains the entry and display Swing components.  I used a `GridBagLayout` to layout the ">" and the display and entry Swing components.  Yes, the `GridBagLayout` looks complicated, but it's the easiest way to create a form with labels in one column and the entry fields in another column.

The button `JPanel` contains the `JButtons`.  I used a `GridLayout` to arrange the `JButtons`.  Yes, I had to put a dummy `JLabel` in column 1, row 2 to make the layout work.

Using Swing layout managers makes the GUI more flexible and allows for the easier addition of Swing components.  Just maximize the GUI to see what happens.

### Controller

I created three `ActionListeners` for the three `JButtons`.  It's much easier to manage separate `ActionListeners` than one complicated `ActionListener`.

I used lambda expressions for the next button and exit button because they were simple `ActionListeners`.  A lambda expression creates an anonymous `ActionListener` class under the covers.

I left the answer button `ActionListener` as an internal method to the view class.  You can see how simple the method is, after creating an application model and view.

## Code

Here's the complete runnable code.  I made all the additional classes inner classes so I could post the code as one block.  You should separate these classes into separate files.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class MathFighter implements ActionListener, Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new MathFighter());
    }

    private final DrawingPanel drawingPanel;

    private JFrame frame;

    private JLabel mathQuestionLabel, responseLabel;

    private JTextField answerField;

    private final MathFighterModel model;

    public MathFighter() {
        this.model = new MathFighterModel();
        this.drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel(model);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame("Math Fighter");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(drawingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createControlPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createControlPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        panel.add(createEntryPanel());
        panel.add(createButtonPanel());

        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createEntryPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 150));
        Border outsideBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5);
        Border insideBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.WHITE, 3);
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(outsideBorder,
                insideBorder));

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 0);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 0.0;
        panel.add(createLabel(">"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx++;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        mathQuestionLabel = createLabel(" ");
        panel.add(mathQuestionLabel, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        gbc.weightx = 0.0;
        panel.add(createLabel(">"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx++;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        answerField = new JTextField(12);
        answerField.setFont(getHeadlineFont());
        answerField.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, -8, 0, 0));
        answerField.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        answerField.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        panel.add(answerField, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        gbc.weightx = 0.0;
        panel.add(createLabel(">"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx++;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        responseLabel = createLabel(" ");
        panel.add(responseLabel, gbc);

        updateEntryPanel();

        return panel;
    }

    private JLabel createLabel(String labelText) {
        JLabel label = new JLabel(labelText);
        label.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        label.setFont(getHeadlineFont());

        return label;
    }

    private JPanel createButtonPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2, 10, 10));
        panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 150));
        Border outsideBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 0, 5, 5);
        Border insideBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.WHITE, 3);
        Border marginBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10);
        Border compoundBorder = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(insideBorder,
                marginBorder);
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(outsideBorder,
                compoundBorder));

        JButton answerButton = createButton("Answer", insideBorder);
        answerButton.addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(answerButton);

        JButton nextButton = createButton("Next", insideBorder);
        nextButton.addActionListener(event -> {
            updateEntryPanel();
        });
        panel.add(nextButton);

        panel.add(new JLabel(" "));

        JButton exitButton = createButton("Exit", insideBorder);
        exitButton.addActionListener(event -> {
            frame.dispose();
            System.exit(0);
        });
        panel.add(exitButton);

        return panel;
    }

    private JButton createButton(String buttonText, Border insideBorder) {
        JButton button = new JButton(buttonText);
        button.setBorder(insideBorder);
        button.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        button.setFont(getHeadlineFont());
        button.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

        return button;
    }

    private Font getHeadlineFont() {
        return new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.BOLD, 16);
    }

    public void updateEntryPanel() {
        mathQuestionLabel.setText(model.generateRandomMathQuestion());
        answerField.setText(" ");
        answerField.requestFocusInWindow();
        responseLabel.setText(" ");
    }

    public void repaint() {
        drawingPanel.repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        try {
            int userAnswer = Integer.valueOf(answerField.getText().trim());
            if (model.isAnswerCorrect(userAnswer)) {
                responseLabel.setText("Correct");
                model.incrementPlayerLife(20);
            } else {
                responseLabel.setText("Incorrect, try another answer");
                model.incrementPlayerLife(-20);
            }
            answerField.requestFocusInWindow();
            repaint();
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
                    "<html><font face='Comic Sans MS' size='3'>INTEGER ONLY, KIDDO");
        }
    }

    public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private final MathFighterModel model;

        public DrawingPanel(MathFighterModel model) {
            this.model = model;
            this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.setFont(getHeadlineFont());

            int width = getWidth();
            int height = getHeight();
            int margin = 20;
            int barHeight = 30;

            int enemyLifePoints = model.getEnemyLifePoints();
            g2d.setColor(calculateBarColor(enemyLifePoints));
            int x = (width - enemyLifePoints) / 2;
            int y = margin;
            g2d.fillRect(x, y, enemyLifePoints, barHeight);
            drawString(g2d, x, y, enemyLifePoints, barHeight);

            int playerLifePoints = model.getPlayerLifePoints();
            g2d.setColor(calculateBarColor(playerLifePoints));
            x = (width - playerLifePoints) / 2;
            y = height - margin - barHeight;
            g2d.fillRect(x, y, playerLifePoints, barHeight);
            drawString(g2d, x, y, playerLifePoints, barHeight);
        }

        private void drawString(Graphics2D g2d, int x, int y, int width,
                int height) {
            String lifePointString = Integer.toString(width);
            FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
            Rectangle2D r = fm.getStringBounds(lifePointString, g2d);
            int a = (width - (int) r.getWidth()) / 2 + x;
            int b = (height - (int) r.getHeight()) / 2 + fm.getAscent() + y;
            g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2d.drawString(lifePointString, a, b);
        }

        private Color calculateBarColor(int lifePoints) {
            int red = 0;
            int green = 204;
            int blue = 0;

            if (lifePoints <= 100) {
                red = 204;
                if (lifePoints <= 40) {
                    green = 0;
                }
            }

            return new Color(red, green, blue);
        }

        private Font getHeadlineFont() {
            return new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.BOLD, 16);
        }

    }

    public class MathFighterModel {

        private int answer, enemyLifePoints, playerLifePoints;

        public MathFighterModel() {
            this.enemyLifePoints = 200;
            this.playerLifePoints = 200;
        }

        public String generateRandomMathQuestion() {
            String questionString = "";
            int questionType = (int) (Math.random() * 4) + 1;
            int number1 = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 10;
            int number2 = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 10;
            int number3 = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 10;

            if (playerLifePoints > 100) {
                if (questionType == 1) {
                    this.answer = number1 + number2;
                    questionString = "What is " + number1 + " + " + number2
                            + " ?";
                } else if (questionType == 2) {
                    this.answer = number1 - number2;
                    questionString = "What is " + number1 + " - " + number2
                            + " ?";
                } else if (questionType == 3) {
                    this.answer = number1 * number2;
                    questionString = "What is " + number1 + " X " + number2
                            + " ?";
                } else if (questionType == 4) {
                    this.answer = number1 * number2 / number3;
                    questionString = "What is " + number1 + " X " + number2
                            + " / " + number3 + " ?";
                }
            } else {
                if (questionType == 1) {
                    this.answer = number1 * number2 + number3;
                    questionString = "What is " + number1 + " X " + number2
                            + " + " + number3 + " ?";
                } else if (questionType == 2) {
                    this.answer = number1 * number2 - number3;
                    questionString = "What is " + number1 + " X " + number2
                            + " + " + number3 + " ?";
                } else if (questionType == 3) {
                    this.answer = (number1 * number2) / (number2 + number3);
                    questionString = "What is (" + number1 + " x " + number2
                            + ") / (" + number2 + " + " + number3 + ") ?";
                } else if (questionType == 4) {
                    this.answer = (number1 * number2) / (number2 - number3);
                    questionString = "What is (" + number1 + " x " + number2
                            + ") / (" + number2 + " - " + number3 + ") ?";
                }
            }

            return questionString;
        }

        public void incrementPlayerLife(int increment) {
            this.playerLifePoints += increment;
            this.enemyLifePoints -= increment;
        }

        public boolean isAnswerCorrect(int userAnswer) {
            return userAnswer == answer;
        }

        public int getEnemyLifePoints() {
            return enemyLifePoints;
        }

        public int getPlayerLifePoints() {
            return playerLifePoints;
        }

    }

}
```